Import skimage.draw error when training MRCNN model
I'm new to this and I'm trying to implement a MRCNN model using these resources:
https://github.com/soumyaiitkgp/Custom_MaskRCNN/tree/master
https://engineering.matterport.com/splash-of-color-instance-segmentation-with-mask-r-cnn-and-tensorflow-7c761e238b46
After changing my values in the custom.py file to my own dataset and running the code. I run into this error:
error
I ran "pip install -r requirements.txt" but I'm not sure why I get this error. Please help, thanks.
Here are the details of the requirements.txt:
numpy
scipy
Pillow
cython
matplotlib
scikit-image
tensorflow>=1.3.0
keras>=2.0.8
opencv-python
h5py
imgaug
IPython[all]

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
